# What task is being returned and why is this task status RanToCompletion

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am rather new to task based programming and trying to determine how to return a task and verify that it has been started. The code that I got to work was not what I was expecting. The console application is as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mySimple = new Simple();
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = mySimple.RunSomethingAsync(cts.Token);
        while (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("It is started");
        Console.ReadKey();
        cts.Cancel();
    }

public class Simple
{
    public async void RunSomething(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(count++);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), token).ContinueWith(task => { });
        }
    }

    public Task RunSomethingAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => this.RunSomething(token));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Starting...
0
It is started
1
2
3
4
```

Why is the task that is being returned have a status as TaskStatus.RanToCompletion compared to TaskStatus.Running as we see that the while loop is still executing? Am I checking the status of the task of putting the RunSomething task on the threadpool rather than the RunSomething task itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RunSomething` is an `async void` method, meaning it exposes no means of the caller ever determining when it finishes, they can only ever start the operation and then have no idea what happens next.  You then wrap a call to it inside of `Task.Run`, this is schedluing a thread pool thread to *start* `RunSomething`.  It will then complete as soon as it has finished *starting* that `Task`.

If `RunSomething` actually returned a `Task`, then the caller would be able to determine when it actually finished, and if you waited on it it wouldn't actually indicate that it was done until that asynchronous operation was actually finished (there would be no reason to use `Task.Run` to start it in another thead, you'd be better off just calling it directly and not wasting the effort of moving that to a thread pool thread).

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use async void (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)
   instead you should use async Task
2. If you need to call an async method from a non-async (such as from a static void main) you should do something like this:

   ```
   mySimple.RunSomethingAsync(cts.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   ```

   That will effectively make the method a synchronous call.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `async void`, but only for events.

Comment: Was this intended as a comment under [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41025145/11178549)'s answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33001575)